# finding the inverse of the sum of prime factorization

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

I'm a little confused on how to find the inverse of the following function $$ \ h:\mathbb{N} \backslash \{1\}\rightarrow \Bbb{N} $$ Be defined as$$h(n) = the \ sum \ of \ factors\ appearing \ in\ the \ prime\ factorization \\$$Example$$ h(12) = 2+2+3$$ Find $$h^{-1}(11)$$The solution gives the following answer$$\{11,18,28,40,45,48,54\}$$I believe they found the inverse to be the product of prime numbers that sum to 11. So for 45$$3\cdot3\cdot5 = 45\\3+3+2 = 11$$how does this show its the inverse? and if im correct in my interpretation why is 18 and 11 in the set? 9 and 1 are not prime$$2+9 =11\\2\cdot9=18\\11\cdot1=11\\1+11=12$$

Comment: The only prime factor of $11$ is $11$. But I agree that $18 = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 3 \notin h^{-1}(11)$.

Comment: wait dont you mean 18 is in the inverse? and 11 shouldnt be in the inverse because you're multiplying an prime with non-prime number?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the inverse of $h$ does not exist, since $h$ is not injective. Actually, you try to define [preimage](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Preimage.html) of $h$.

Comment: i) wait dont you mean 18 is in the inverse: no! $h(18) = 8 \neq 11$. ii) 11 shouldnt be in the inverse because there is no prime factors that add to 11 to get 11 correct?  No! 11 is the only prime factor of eleven, hence $h(11) = 11$.

Comment: i get that 11 is the only prime factor of 11 but dont you have to add 1 to 11? thats whats going on with 45 for example

Comment: The number 1 is not part of the prime factorization of a number (per definition). This definition makes sense, because otherwise the prime factorization would stop to be unique (up to order). Also, I agree that 18 should  not be in the set of solutions. To me, this looks like a mistake.